# How to setup view to filter based on second URL parameter?

Tags: views, 8

We have a view, `myview`, that is added to the `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/` page. It has an exposed filter, `Topic` that a person can use to filter the user where `Ajax = Enabled` so that it loads the results without refreshing the page.

The view is added to a landing page (`content type = basic`) and at the bottom of the page. It is meant to return nodes where `topic` tag value is equal to what is supplied from the url.

Taxonomy term values (topic):

1. IoT
2. Cloud
3. Cloud Security

**How to setup view to filter based on second URL parameter?**

Expected behavior:

1. Display all items when `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/` is loaded.
2. Display all items where `topic = Cloud Security` when `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/cloud-security` is loaded
3. Display all items where `topic = Cloud` when `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/cloud` is loaded

Current Behavior:

1. Displays all items when loading `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/`
2. Displays no items when loading `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/cloud`

**What we have tried using `block display type`:**

1. Create view using `block display type` with a contextual filter `Content: topic`
2. `When filter value is not available` = `Display all results for the specified field`
3. `When the filter value is available or a default is provided` is set to `Specify Validation Criteria = enabled`, `Validator = Taxonomy Term Name`, `Vocabulary = topic`, and `Action to take if filter value does not validate = Display all results for the specified field`

**What we tried using `Page display type`:**

[image: setting]

1. add path `/some-path` (without `%`)
2. Add relationship, `field_topic: taxonomy term` and `require relationship = true`
3. Add contextual filter: `Name from Taxonomy term (field_topic)` with the following settings below.

Contextual filter settings:

[image: not in the url]

`When the filter value is not in the URL`

- Display all results for the specified field

[image: topic]
[image: case]
[image: more]

`When the filter value is in the url or a default is provided`

- `Specify validation criteria` = `Validator = Taxonomy term name`
- `Vocabulary` = `Topic`
- `Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values` = true
- `Action to take if filter value does not validate` = Display a summary
- `Case` = Lower case
- `Case in path` = lower case
- `More` = `Transform spaces to dashes in url = enabled`

Comment: Is this a content view, or taxonomy term view? Are you listing nodes or terms in your views results?

Comment: @prkos updated the question to include this information. Basically it is a `content view` where the results are nodes where `topic` is equal to the one from the url. If the value is not added to the url then it should return all.

Comment: Instead of using term name in contexual filter use "has taxonomy term"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content Views don't have access to Taxonomy term name information out of the box, you only have term ID available. So even if you add the Taxonomy term field as the contextual filter and set the `Validator = Taxonomy Term Name` you're not telling it what to use, you're basically making a mistake trying to use that validator.

You can test this if you enter the term ID into the Preview instead of the name, or set the `Action to take if filter value does not validate` to `Display a Summary` and see what you get as output ;)

### Add term name info through Relationship

To introduce the term name information into your content views you have to:

1. add a Relationship to the term: `Taxonomy term referenced from field_topic`. Require it if you only want to list nodes that have a topic assigned.

   Now you will see a new Category of fields when adding Contextual filters: `Taxonomy term`
2. Add the Contextual filter `Name` from `Taxonomy term` Category, it will use the Relationship from previous step by default, and configure it:
   `When filter value is not available`
   **Display all results for the specified field**
   `When the filter value is available or a default is provided`
    **Specify validation criteria**
   **Taxonomy term name**
   [Case settings, other relevant config as you see fit]

You will now see all results when visiting the main path, and if you visit the path with topic name appended the list will be filtered to show only nodes with that topic.

---

### In case you have terms with the same name accross vocabularies

There is a bug that kicks in sometimes  when using term name as the Validator, if you have different terms with the same term name: [TermName views argument_validator is not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2494617).

The patch from that issue is working, as reported by the question author usernameabc, so it can be used until a new version is released that includes it.

Comment: any reason why when use the `Preview with contextual filters`, if i add a value from the `topic` as long as it is a single word, it works. If i type `cloud`, it returns what I want. When i type `cloud-security`, then zero results (even when `transform dashes in url to spaces in term names filters values = enabled`). Also, when i visit `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/`, then it works, but when I navigate to `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/cloud` i get a `404` page. Any thoughts as to what else i am missing?

Comment: There is one more option you need if you want dashes in URL: `Transform spaces to dashes in URL` under the last Fieldset `More` at the bottom of the contextual configuration popup. If Page is behaving differently from Preview, it's often about how the contextual argument is fed to the views. Do you have `%` appended to your Path? You probably need to remove it because you have set to show all results, and not provide a default. Also to debug: change to show a Summary instead of Page not found when the filter doesn't validate, then type some gibberish word and see the links you get in Summary.

Comment: for some reason, enabling that setting worked, but it is only working for single word. When using `cloud-security` in the url, I get `page not found`, but if i used `cloud`, then it filters. Why would that be?

Comment: See my last comment above, you didn't report back about debug with Summary. You should also probably post your contextual and other configuration, otherwise it's a guessing game.

Comment: i did not get any results displayed. The question is also updated with more information.

Comment: What is the Contextual configuration under `More` fieldset (at the bottom)? Did you test by entering `https://www.adomain.com/some-page/wrong`? You should see a Summary list of topics, you will be able to see what Drupal did to spaces in "Cloud security".

Comment: i added all view screenshots. Under `more`, only `Transform spaces to dashes in URL` is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots, seems identical to my case, apart from Infinite scroll - can you try to use a normal pager and see if it helps, and I don't have anything under Header but I don't expect problems there. If you enter a non-existent tag into Preview (so the contextual filter doesn't validate) you should see the Summary, which is a list of your tags with numbers in brackets showing how many nodes in each tag. This can help you show what the link should be for the tags with spaces.

Comment: i am at a loss for words. for some reason `some-path/cloud-security` and `some-path/cloud%20security` return the summary list instead of the action items. `Cloud` works, but not `IoT` even when the `Case` settings to all lowercase. I am seeing the `summary` list now except it just says `cloud security (1)` when `some-path/cloud-security` is the `url`

Comment: What happens when you click on the link in Summary (on the actual page), it seems that it should be the correct URl.

Comment: when i click, it refreshes the page with `some-path/cloud-security?field_topic_target_id=all`

Comment: in order to get this to work i had to use [TermName views argument_validator is not working as expected](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2494617) patch. Then it started to work for all the values. can you add this to your solution and i will mark it best since it actually led to my solution?

Comment: Does this mean that you have terms with the same name in different vocabularies (different TID but same term name)?

Comment: yes i did some digging and found different `vocabularies` with the same term name. However they have different meanings thus they are in different `vocabularies`

Comment: Yes that makes sense, and it is a bug, the Validator should mind the chosen Vocabulary. I was curious that if it maybe isn't the case of the same name in different Vocabularies it might be the smilar term name with a space inside (cloud and cloud-security), but it is that bug in the end. I hope they release the patched version soon and I'm glad you finally got it fully working.